# Kubernetes Ingress Controller Error when exposing application

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to expose my backend API service using the nginx Ingress controller. Here is the Ingress service that I have defined:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: plant-simulator-ingress
  namespace: plant-simulator-ns
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/path:   /metrics
    prometheus.io/port:   '80'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: grafana.local
      http:
        paths: 
          - backend: 
              serviceName: grafana-ip-service
              servicePort: 8080

    - host: prometheus.local
      http:
        paths: 
          - backend: 
              serviceName: prometheus-ip-service
              servicePort: 8080 

    - host: plant-simulator.local
      http:
        paths: 
          - backend: 
              serviceName: plant-simulator-service
              servicePort: 9000
```

The plant-simulator-service is defined as a service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: plant-simulator-service
  namespace: plant-simulator-ns
  labels:
    name: plant-simulator-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9000 
      targetPort: 9000 
      protocol: TCP
      name: plant-simulator-service-port
  selector:
    app: plant-simulator
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I successfully deployed this on my Minikube and here is the set of pods running:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ joesan$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE            NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system          coredns-6955765f44-cvblh           1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system          coredns-6955765f44-xh2wg           1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system          etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system          kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system          kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system          kube-proxy-n6scg                   1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system          kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          39m
kube-system          storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   0          39m
plant-simulator-ns   flux-5476b788b9-g7xtn              1/1     Running   0          20m
plant-simulator-ns   memcached-86bdf9f56b-zgshx         1/1     Running   0          20m
plant-simulator-ns   plant-simulator-6d46dc89cb-xsjgv   1/1     Running   0          65s
```

Here is the list of services:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ joesan$ minikube service list
|--------------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------|-----|
|     NAMESPACE      |          NAME           |         TARGET PORT         | URL |
|--------------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------|-----|
| default            | kubernetes              | No node port                |
| kube-system        | kube-dns                | No node port                |
| plant-simulator-ns | memcached               | No node port                |
| plant-simulator-ns | plant-simulator-service | http://192.168.99.103:32638 |
|--------------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------|-----|
```

What I wanted to achieve is that my application backend is reachable via the dns entry that I have configured in my Ingress -

> plant-simulator.local

Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Dealing with Ingress in minikube is very sensitive to which hypervisor you are using, mind telling which Hypervisor you are using? can you also test if the service is reachable on `192.168.99.103:32638` ? as soon as you answer I can proceed with the troubleshooting

Comment: I fixed this by adding the mapping to the hostname and ip address in the /etc/hosts file and it worked!

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but there were too many variables, I preferred to ask you first. You can write an answer to help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP reported the case was solved by adding the IP and Hostname in the `/etc/hosts`

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
192.168.99.103  plant-simulator.local
```